# chrome update Crashou Css

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, google-chrome

Estou com um problema no css da minha aplicação web. Comecei a trabalhar nessa empresa à algumas semanas como estagiário e estou tendo que resolver alguns bugs que apareceram, principalmente relacionados ao google chrome. Acontece que depois da atualização do dia 10/12 aproximadamente, a nossa aplicação começou a apresentar alguns bugs.

Trabalhamos com uma tabela e dentro dessa tabela, existem quadros com tarefas. Seguem imagens de como funciona e como deveria funcionar.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPAS0.jpg
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois que pesquisar um pouco, acabamos descobrindo que em uma parte do código, mais especificamente o `tr` `td` que cuida de outras `divs` está *bugado*. O `height:100%` está funcionando, mas este está zerando os outros `heights` dentro dele. Se tirarmos esse `height:100%` as tarefas voltam a aparecer e oque *buga* é a `jquery:droppable`, que vocês podem ver nas imagens mencionadas acima.

Uma solução para o problema, foi colocar `height:-webkit-calc(1px)`, visto que este problema é apenas para o chrome. Funcionou? Sim, é a solução ideal? Muito provavelmente não. Gostaria da ajuda de vocês para me ajudar, como eu disse, sou um estagiário e estou um pouco perdido, pois nunca tive experiências anteriores.

Segue um trecho do código, o restante pode ser encontrando no link do fiddle.

```
    <tr data-bind="attr:{id: sequencial}" id="2093" class ="selectable">
    <td class ="historia" style="height:1px">
      <div class="colapsada" style="display:none;">
      </div>
      <div class="expandida">
        <div class="historiaLayout">
          <span id=""></span>
        </div>
      </div> 
     </td>
      <!-- ko foreach: {data: $root.fases, as : 'fase'} -->      
   <td data-bind="css : 'fase-' + id" class="fase-7">
     <div class="colapsada"></div>
     <div class="expandida tarefaExpandida">
       <div class="nomeFase fase">
                        <span class="tamanhoVariavel sh-tooltip" data-bind="text: titulo, attr: {'aria-label': titulo}" aria-label="A Fazer">A Fazer</span>
            }
    .tabelaQT tbody tr td {
    border-right: 1px #ccc solid;
    height: 100%;
}
.tarefaExpandida {
    margin: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rychardgoltara/bvw1hkxg/

Comment: Posta um exemplo que possamos executar.

Comment: então, acontece que não sei bem como fazer um exemplo executável do problema, sou novo na área ainda.